I can't import XYZ file into Blender using Atomic
I am trying to import an xyz format to blender, but suddenly this error message appears. Any idea?. I am using Blender 2.92.


According XYZ file format, first line should be an integer "". From Python trace, I infer that such a line is missing in your file, as 3 real numbers are red.
